# Select specific columns in hierarchical data with Ef Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**I want to use the functionality of EF Core to automatically map self references to child lists even when I load a flat structure. In addition, I want to be able to reduce the number of columns read and transferred.**

My self referencing data structure:

```
public class Item 
{
    public int property1 { get; set; }
    /*
        Realy long list of columns
    */
    public int property30 { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentOid { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to achieve loading of the whole hierarchical Tree which can be done easily by using the following query:

```
(DbContext context) =>  context.Items.AsQueryable()
```

And afterwards filtering with:

```
var rootNodes = items.Where(f => f.ParentOid == null)
```

**This way Ef Core already filled the Children collection on all Children in the tree, this is the behavior that I need!**

This query transfers quite huge amounts of data because property1 - property30 are all loaded while I just need a small subset of them.

By using the LINQ select statement with anonymous types, I'm  loosing the behavior of building up the tree automatically and I would have to do that by myself.

**My current solution**

By setting up another model Item.cs without the properties, I don't need their presence in the select statement of the SQL query.

My problem with this solution is that I need to change the name of Item.cs to e.g.  ItemWithLessProperties.cs and add it to the current context. This would create a conflict in OtherObject.cs because its holding references of Item and not ItemWithLessProperties. So, I would have to copy this one and add it to the context as well.

By using a total different context for this purpose, I would also have duplicates of the Models Item (which is not a big problem) and OtherObject (which is a problem, because there are multiple of those).

Comment: As the many duplicate questions show, you can't. Not even in SQL. What you do right now isn't loading the tree. `(DbContext context) =>  context.Items.AsQueryable()` doesn't load a tree, it loads everything *without* rebuilding the tree. You need a recursive CTE to perform a hierarchical query in SQL. Specific databases make this easier, eg if you use `hierarchyid` in SQL Server you can get rid of recursive CTEs

Comment: If you can't use `hierarchyid` you'll have to use a recursive CTE with `FromSqlRaw` and build the rest of your query around it. Check [this example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-a-recursive-common-table-expression-to-display-multiple-levels-of-recursion) that shows how to write a recursive query in SQL

Comment: Since i load everything (in my real code i have filtering where statements so i don't load the whole table) ef core automatically hangs childs with a fitting ParentOid in the Children list of the parent.
So i don't have problems loading the tree structure! 
My problem is reducing the size of Items in the tree by using a select statement won't work with the automatic children list building. Therefore i used the hack by reducing the amount of properties in the Item Model so they don't occur in the sql query.

Comment: Why do you perform a manual filtering step then? This isn't an opinion - if you want hierarchical queries, you need recursive CTEs. Without them you *can't filter* the data, you have to load everything in memory. You simply can't know which node to load and which not when executing the query.

Comment: To only select the root elements of the trees

Comment: `By using the linq select statement with anonymous types I'm loosing the behavior of building up the tree automatically` because you're not using a recursive CTE, you depend on magic that only happens when you load the full entities. "Magic" that isn't even specific to hierarchical queries (which EF knows nothing about). EF reconstructs relations after loading all objects from the database, based on the PK/FK values. When you use `Select` to select a subset of the entities, the relations have no meaning any more

Comment: When you use `Select` you instruct EF to create a `SELECT` statement that only returns the columns you asked for. If no PK, FK values are returned, neither EF nor a human would be able to reconstruct hierarchies. Even if you include them in `Select` and even if you add `Children`, what type would those children be?

Comment: Yes you hit the point. I rely on the reconstruction EF core does. In my case i know which nodes i have to load because my selection is based on properties directly on the node itself `(DbContext context) =>  context.Items.Where(item => item.Property1 == requirement)` So I guess there is no way of bringing back the meaning and therefore the magic happening of the Keys when using a Select statement?

Comment: So maybe I will then stay with my current Solution and have multiple database models for this purpose. Thats a bit of duplicated code and either a second dbContext or a more messy context but it works exactly as I want it to behave. Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an  `ItemDTO`. You can create an object like

```
public class ItemDTO 
{
    /*
        Properties you need
    */
    public int property1 { get; set; }
    public int property5 { get; set; }
    public int property17 { get; set; }
    public int property30 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And also for every nested entity a DTO if you want to also include it in the queryable.

Then you can simply `var dtoItems = context.Items.Where(condition).Select(i=>new ItemDTO {/* initialize props */});`

**Note**:
If you are not using a DTO and if the data you pull would be strictly read only and you won't try to update the currently pulled entries in the database it's a good option to also use `.AsNoTracking()` to avoid the change tracking overhead of EF Core.

Comment: But OP statet "By using the linq select statement with anonymous types I'm loosing the behavior of building up the tree automatically and I would have to do that by myself." Or is there a way to map again the relations with anonymous types? If yes please elaborate.

Comment: @Sjoerd222888 the OP isn't performing a hierarchical query in the first place. LINQ or EF can't generate hierarchical queries out-of-the-box